# Show alert when radio button value is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, radio-button

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function radio_form(){
   var selectvalue = $('input[name=choice]:checked', '#radio_form').val();

if(selectvalue == "V1"){
   alert('Value 1');
   return true;
}else if(selectvalue == "V2"){
   alert('Value 2');
   return true;
}else if(selectvalue == 'V3'){
   alert('Value 3');
   return true;
}else if(selectvalue == 'V4'){
   alert('Value 4');
   return true;
}
return false;
};
</script>

<form id="radio_form">
  <input type="radio" onclick="radio_form()"  name="choice" value="V1"> 
  <input type="radio" onclick="radio_form()" name="choice" value="V2"> 
  <input type="radio" onclick="radio_form()" name="choice" value="V3">
  <input type="radio" onclick="radio_form()" name="choice" value="V4"> 
</form>
```

I am trying to show an alert when a radio value is selected...however this approach doesn't seem to work.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you are using jquery all you need is ($(this).val()) and a click function -- demo -- http://jsfiddle.net/z66fbof2/

Comment: @TasosAnastasiou Am i able to redirect to a url for example?

Comment: from the radio choice i assume?? yes change the value to "http://somesite.com" and see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `change` event instead of the `click` event. The change event will only trigger when the value of the checkboxes changes, the click event will trigger everytime you click on them, even if you click on the one that is already selected. Also, instead of using inline events, just use a jQuery selector to attach the event to all of the checkboxes.

```js
$("#radio_form input[type=radio]").change(function () {
    alert( 'Redirecting to: .../' + $(this).val() );
    // This will redirect to the value, relative to the current path
    location.href = $(this).val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="radio_form">
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="V1"> 
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="V2"> 
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="V3">
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="V4"> 
</form>
```

Comment: Cant seem to get it to work, this is what I have: `<script type="text/javascript">
$("#language_radio input[type=radio]").change(function () {
    alert( 'Redirecting to: .../' + $(this).val() );
    // This will redirect to the value, relative to the current path
    location.href = $(this).val();
});
</script>`

Comment: `<div id="language-container">
 <form id="language_radio">
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="V1" id="v1"> <label for="v1">V1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="V2" id="v2"> <label for="v2">V2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="V3" id="v3"> <label for="v3">V3</label>
  <input type="radio" name="choice" value="V4" id="v4"> <label for="v4">V4</label> 
 </form>
</div>`

Comment: The script tag should be after your `language-container` div (and all of its contents), is that the case?

Comment: Yes, [IMG](http://s2.postimg.org/kh0lpdyg7/Screen_Shot_2015_05_17_at_3_37_37_AM.png)

Comment: Weird... Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/x86rsgx6/. Exactly the same code. Of course, you are positive jQuery is loading? Do you use it anywhere else before that, and load it before this script? Make sure it's loaded before (and that it actually loads) and you can also open up the console (`CTRL + SHIFT + I`) and type `jQuery` to see if its there.
Also, what does not work?. No alert shows up at all?

Comment: Alright, got it to work somehow now... Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Haha, alright, glad it worked at last : ) No problem.